Removing the colour of links in contents (& lists)
After using \hypersetup{colorlinks=true} to remove the boxes and colour the links in my document, is there an option to remove the coloring for the contents (& other lists)? I don't particularly like such a large block of coloured text.
I note the option to remove the links completely by setting linktoc=none, however I would still like to keep the links.

Sorry about answering my own question, but I've since discovered the answer to this...
Use \begingroup ... \endgroup to redefine the \hypersetup just for the group, e.g.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures (e.g.)
\endgroup

\section{Introduction}...


You can accept own answer ...
